# How to manage user permissions after payment with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, web-development-server

i want to make an app with Vue where a user only get certain permissions, like write a post, after payment, but I don't understand how that can be done. There is any content where this is explained, or anyone can point me a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[VueAcl](https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-acl)

That's a pretty good permission check plugin that you can check out